# Can you reverse the total? (Looping C)

Tags: c, if-statement, reverse

"can you reverse the number" is the number already reverse by using Mod(%). My question, can it be reversed to normal?

For example, if you enter the number "2552" it'll change to "2+5+5+2", which is correct, but, when you enter another number like "4125" it will change to "5+2+1+4" instead of "4+1+2+5"

Ok, I just entered the programming world, a newcomer

With the "if" can it add "+" without exceeding the number like "4+1+2+5+"
there are "+" after "5", how can I delete this extra "+"?

```
#include <stdio.h>
main(){
int a, b, h=0;
    printf("Enter the number : ");
    scanf("%d",&a);

    printf("%d = ", a);

    while(a != 0)
    {
        b=a%10;
        a=a/10;
        printf("%d",b);
        if(b != a)
        {
            printf("+");
        }
        h=h+b;
    }
    printf(" = %d\n", h);

}
```

Comment: Please try to ask a specific question and leave out stuff like "OK", "I mean", "Hm". This reads like you're talking to yourself, being confused.

Comment: I don't understand your question.  What output do you want?  What output are you currently getting.

Comment: not clear what is the question. What I understood is: You want to know how to print the `+` only between two digits, but not after the last one. Is that correct?

Comment: Well done @François - I have no idea who approved putting in those back-ticks, but they were not an improvement.

Comment: @MartinBonner I did by accident when I tried to remove the c++ tag, sorry. Just cleaning up my own mess.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux : Fair enough (easily done).

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35372784/idioms-for-for-each-except-the-last-or-between-each-consecutive-pair-of-el/35373017#35373017

Answer (score 1):

Instead of scanning for an actual number, you can scan a string from the user. Strings are easy to reverse:

```
char num[5]; // Has the input
char rev[5]; // Will have the reverse
int len = strlen(num);
rev[len] = 0; // End the string
for(int i = 0; i < len; i++){
    rev[i] = num[len-i-1];
}
```

Comment: This code is a little hard to follow, so I wasn't paying attention to the right things. Those buffers are scary small, though.

Comment: @tadman Their size can be increased via substituting the '5' with a number that is greater in size ;)

Comment: Sarcasm aside, there's an extremely high probability someone will type in a number over 5 characters long. Why not 255? Or 1024? Or something someone's less likely to pop by pure accident?

Comment: @tadman Yes, that might be appropriate, but is in no way essential to the example I provided. Also, +1 for using powers of two for buffer sizes (although 256 is the *nitpick* right size).

Comment: 255 has a long tradition in the database world, it's the longest length an 8-bit variable length indicator can handle, and 1024 is a good default for a generic "buffer". This of course glosses over how dangerous C can be if not kept on a very tight leash when it comes to strings in general.

Comment: @tadman Cool, but wouldn't the buffer size still be 256? As it is null-terminated, the length would be 255.

Comment: In the database context it's effectively a Pascal-style string so there's no null-terminator, and null values are not significant. It takes the form of one byte length field, (up to) 255 bytes of data.

Comment: @tadman Okay, interesting.. Haven't done a lot with databases yet. But thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can go backwards by taking the highest digits in your number first instead of the lowest, e.g. like so:

```
int currentLog10;
int powerOfTenForCurrentDigit;

...

while(a != 0)
{
  currentLog10 = (int)log10(a);

  powerOfTenForCurrentDigit = (int)pow(10, currentLog10);

  b = a/powerOfTenForCurrentDigit;
  a = a - b * powerOfTenForCurrentDigit;

  ...
}
```

How does it work:

- log10 of 4125 will give us 3.
- b is set to 4125 devided by 1000 (10^3) = 4.
- a is set to 4125 - 4 * 1000 = 125
- Next step log10 of 125 gives 2, we devide by 10^2 (100) and so on.
- Last step 5 gives 0, 5 devided by 10^0 (1) gives 5, a becomes 5 - 5 * 1, which is 0, we are done.

You have to be careful in edge cases, where log10 returns something like (n-1).999999999 instead of n, but it shouldn't happen for small numbers as are entered in your program. Maybe add some sanity check for the input.