# Create string according to the parameter pack arguments count

Tags: c++, fmt, parameter-pack

I have a function with a parameter pack, I pass this pack to the `fmt::format` function, and I want to create a `formatStr` according to the args count, meaning add "{}#" for each passed argument.

I can do it using iterating, but is it possible to do this with one line solution?
How to do it gracefully?

```
    template <typename... Args>
    void formatArgs( Args&&...args)
    {
        const auto size = sizeof...(Args);
        std::string formatStr = ...// "{}#{}#{}..." - {}# should depend on args count
        
        /* 
        std::ostringstream formatStr;
        for (const auto& p : { args... })
            formatStr << {}#";
        */
    
        auto res = fmt::format(formatStr.c_str(), args...);
        ...
    }
```

Comment: Why use `printf` here? Why not use `std::cout` to print the arguments? It's possible with [fold](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/fold) expressions. Also see [this old question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51281811/print-spaces-between-each-element-using-a-fold-expression) for a few ways to add characters in between arguments.

Comment: Of use overloading to print (still with `std::cout`): One function for a single argument (to handle the last one) and one with one argument plus the parameter pack. Doing it this way should be plenty of examples for.

Comment: Ok, I don't use `printf`, I use `fmt::format` function and I need to create a string like "{}#{}#{}..."  from the param pack

Comment: Is the use of `std::format` mandatory? Otherwise you could use `std::ostringstream` and parameter pack folding to create the string directly from the arguments.

Comment: Alexandr, I think you made it impossible for the people that know fmt intimately to find your question by posting this printf "distraction". Don't do such things!

Comment: @MarcusMüller I corrected my question, thanks!

Comment: hm why the format string? Does the `fmt::join` functionality not do what you want?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude do you propose to iterate over this pack as in my example?

Comment: @MarcusMüller, could you please share an example with `fmt::join` ?

Comment: I'd try, but I don't know what your formatted string should look like in the end, or what the things in your args are.

Answer (score 4):

An ugly fold expression would work. It's only redeeming quality is that it's just one line, and in C++20 it should be a constexpr, so in C++20 this'll wind up to be a single `std::string` constructor call:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

template<typename ...Args>
std::string string_from_args(Args && ...args)
{
    return std::string{ ((args, std::string{"%s#"}) + ...) };
}

int main()
{
    std::cout << string_from_args(1, 2, 3, 4) << "\n";

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Yep, I'm still looking for a `constexpr` solution

Comment: Some way, some how, strings must get concatenated. This is `constexpr` only in C++20.

Comment: @SamVarshvchik do you mean make this function `constexpr` ?

Comment: Yes, I suppose that it can be explicitly `constexpr`, but this function is just a demonstration of the fold expression it uses. Just put the fold expression, itself, into yours'.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to create a string with all the arguments I suggest you use an `std::ostringstream` to create the string directly instead of going through `std::format` or similar.

How to create the string differs between version of C++. Before C++17 and pre-fold you can use overloading of functions to handle the argument packs:

```
// Handle single-argument string construction
template<typename Arg>
std::string string_from_args(Arg&& arg)
{
    return (std::ostringstream() << arg).str();
}

// Handle multiple-argument string construction
template<typename First, typename ...Rest>
std::string string_from_args(First&& first, Rest&& ...rest)
{
    return (std::ostringstream() << string_from_args(first) << '#' << string_from_args(rest...)).str();
}
```

Then with fold-expressions introduced in C++17:

```
template<typename ...Args>
std::string string_from_args(Args&& ...args)
{
    char const* separator = "";
    std::ostringstream os;
    (((os << separator << args), separator = "#"), ...);
    return os.str();
}
```

With a simple `main` function

```
int main()
{
    std::cout << string_from_args(123, 456.789, "foo", 'b');
}
```

both variants should construct and print the string

```
123#456.789#foo#b
```

Answer (score 1):

If all arguments have the same type which seems to be the case considering that your current solution involves iteration then you could use [`fmt::join`](https://fmt.dev/latest/api.html#_CPPv4I0EN3fmt4joinE9join_viewIN6detail10iterator_tI5RangeEEN6detail10sentinel_tI5RangeEEERR5Range11string_view). For example:

```cpp
#include <fmt/ranges.h>

template <typename... Args>
std::string formatArgs(Args&&... args) {
  return fmt::format("{}", fmt::join({args...}, ""));
}

int main() {
  fmt::print("{}", formatArgs(1, 2, 3));
}
```

prints

```
123
```