# C++ cout inside loop for printing vector of vectors fails

Tags: c++, vector

```
template<typename s>
void vecprint2d(const s& vec){
    cout<<"{"<<endl;
    for(int x = 0; x < vec.size(); x++){
        cout<<"{";
        for(int y = 0; y < vec[x].size() - 1;y++){
            cout << vec[x][y]<<", ";
        }
        cout<<vec[x][vec[x].size() - 1]<<"}"<<endl;
    }
    cout<<"}"<<endl;
}


int main(){
vector<vector<int>> vec = {{1,2,3},{},{4,5,6}};
vecprint2d(vec);
return 0;
}
```

in my attempt at a function for printing a vector of vectors,
why does cout inside the inner loop cause problems, or is the problem elsewhere?

the output right now looks like:

> {
>
> {

Comment: give an example of call

Comment: How are you calling this function? Please add the calling code snippet also.

Comment: [cannot reproduce](https://wandbox.org/permlink/ojjdbGotavyZnfqt)

Comment: is this really the code you are running to get that output? (i know it isnt, because there is a missing `}` but I dont know if this is just a typo here or if you typed code here that it completely different from your real code)

Comment: your code will access index -1 if one of the inner vectors is empty

Comment: Other than the missing `}` pointed out by @idclev463035818 and a missing `int` before `main`, your posted code gives me the output you/I would expect (VS2019/MSVC or clang-cl).

Comment: well if that is the input it is understandable why the function does not work properly....

Comment: i left out an empty set of {} in vec in the example, does that make a differnece?

Comment: the difference is that this code is invalid while the one before was ok and there was no way to explain the output you got. Details do matter!

Comment: i see whats wrong now thanks, sorry about that

Comment: [Idioms-for-for-each-except-the-last](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35372784/idioms-for-for-each-except-the-last-or-between-each-consecutive-pair-of-el/35373017#35373017) might interest you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the inner vector's `size` is 0, `size() - 1` will overflow and it will loop forever and/or crash. Could that be what is happening on your raspberry pi?

To avoid this, handle `0`-sized vectors as well.

For example like this:

```
template<typename s>
void vecprint2d(const s& vec) {
    cout << "{" << endl;
    for (auto const& row : vec) {
        cout << "{";
        int i = 0;
        for (auto const& val : row) {
            if (i++)
                cout << ", ";
            cout << val;
        }
        cout << "}" << endl;
    }
    cout << "}" << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `size()` function of an empty vector will return an (unsigned) value of **zero** and, in your inner loop, you test `y` against `vec[x].size() - 1`. This will give a value that has 'underflowed' and thus have the **maximum** value that a `size_t` variable can hold, so the `y` loop will run a very large number of times! However, it will likely fail on the first loop, because trying to access ***any*** element of an empty `vector` is [undefined behaviour](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/operator_at).

To fix this, enclose your inner loop in an "is it empty" `if` block (in fact, you should do this for *both* loops). Here's a possible solution:

```cpp
template<typename s>
void vecprint2d(const s& vec)
{
    cout << "{" << endl;;
    if (!vec.empty()) for (size_t x = 0; x < vec.size(); x++) {
        cout << "{";
        if (!vec[x].empty()) {
            for (size_t y = 0; y < vec[x].size() - 1; y++) {
                cout << vec[x][y] << ", ";
            }
            cout << vec[x][vec[x].size() - 1];
        }
        cout << "}" << endl;
    }
    cout << "}" << endl;
}
```

Feel free to ask for further clarification and/or explanation.