# Printing an array line by line but not ending with '\n' on the last line?

Tags: c++, printing, endl

I am currently working on a program and one of the instructions states:

> "For the output file, when outputting for one command, the data should
>   be in one line without “\n”. When outputting for a new command, a new
>   line should  be started."

Would the best option in this case be to have a counter for the amount of commands and then checking if it's greater than 1, if it is then `cout << data << endl;` until you've reached the last one and then `cout << data;`? I feel like that's a really inefficient way of doing this and there is a better solution than this? Thank you!

Comment: it's not very clear to me. can you please add some more detail?

Comment: Given the instructions, that does not appear to be the intended approach. Your approach outputs data **with** '"\n"', does it not?

Comment: I'm given an array of integers and the file I am reading will give me commands to traverse a tree in either preorder, postorder and inorder with the integers. I am suppose to output the integers in by whatever command I am given. When outputting the data should be in one line without “\n”. When outputting for a new command, a new line should be started.

Answer (score 2):

[idioms-for-for-each-between-each-consecutive-pair-of-elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35372784/idioms-for-for-each-except-the-last-or-between-each-consecutive-pair-of-el/35373017#35373017) does mostly literally *"When outputting for a new command, a new line should be started."*

```
const auto* separator = "\n";
const auto* sep = "";
for(const auto& command : commands) {
    std::cout << sep << command;
    sep = separator; // No longer first command
}
```