# How to remove extra space in output of code?

Tags: c++

Help! I am trying to print  my code is giving the correct output BUT with an extra space that is not supposed to be there.

```
   for (int i = i; i <= input; i++)
   {
        cout << factorial(input)/ (factorial(i) * factorial (input - i)) << " ";
   }
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Related to [idiom-for-iterating-between-each-consecutive-pair-of-elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35372784/idiom-for-iterating-between-each-consecutive-pair-of-elements)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dont pad with space at the end on the last element

```
   for (int i = 1; i <= input; i++)
   {
        cout << factorial(input)/ (factorial(i) * factorial (input - i));
        if(i < input)
          cout << " ";
   }
```