# How to remove the end space in this for loop in c++/cpp?

Tags: c++, algorithm, for-loop

```
int n;
cin >> n; cin.ignore();

for(int i = 1; i < 11; i++){
    cout << i * n << " ";// stop printing space at the end number
}
```

> Desired output-> "1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10"

Comment: `if(i != 1) cout << ' ';` before `cout << i * n;`

Comment: Well, don't print it. Either use a conditional or print the first element (without a trailing space) and then the other elements, *preceded* by a space. You may want to end the line with a `'\n'`, though.

Comment: Don't print the extra space, see [idiom-for-iterating-between-each-consecutive-pair-of-elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35372784/idiom-for-iterating-between-each-consecutive-pair-of-elements)

Comment: Here's how to figure this out, this always works! Take out a blank sheet of paper. Write down a step-by-step process of doing this, as short, brief sentences in plain English. [Have your rubber duck review your plan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging). We always refer such questions to their rubber duck. After your rubber duck approves your proposed plan of action, simply take what you've written down and translate it directly into C++, and you're done! Have you discussed this with your rubber duck, yet?

Comment: @SamVarshavchik onwards, I will use the rubber duck method, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple approach is the following

```
for( int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
    if ( i ) cout << ' ';
    cout << ( i + 1 ) * n;
}
```

or

```
for( int i = 1; i < 11; i++){
    if ( i != 1 ) cout << ' ';
    cout << i * n;
}
```

Comment: I don't think you should've rewritten the bounds for this. When _not_ accessing arrays iterating from `1` is entirely acceptable and in this case makes perfect sense.

Answer (score 2):

The standard approach is to use a boolean variable, which is one time either true or false, then print a space or not, depending on the boolean, and set the boolen to a new value.

Often the output of the space in the loop is done first and then then value.

Example:

```
bool printSpace = false;
for(int i = 1; i < 11; ++i) {
    if (printSpace) std::cout << ' ';
    printSpace = true;
    std::cout << i * n;
}
```

You could also use `std::exchange` for flipping the bool. Please read [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/exchange).

Then you could do something like the below:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <utility>

int main() {
    
    std::vector data{1,2,3,4};
    
    bool showComma{};
    for (const int i: data) 
        std::cout << (std::exchange(showComma, true) ? "," : "") << i;
}
```

---

And the super high sophisticated stuff will be done with the `std::ostream_joiner`.

Reade [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/ostream_joiner) for an example. But, unfortunately this is not available for many installations.

Comment: *"The standard approach"* Why more standard than alternatives?

Comment: I used extra variable, but not a boolean (and no branching :-) ) with [my answer for idiom-for-iterating-between-each-consecutive-pair-of-elements](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35373017/2684539) (And I won't qualify my way of standard neither). Sorry to nit-picking for wording. (*"simple"* seems more appropriate than *"standard"* IMO).

Answer (score 0):

One-liner:

```
cout << (i > 1 ? " " : "") << i * n;
```

---

Note: I prefer the "prefix" form because the starting value is easier to know than the ending one (`>1` vs. `>9`).