# May the part of conditional expression be optimised out?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer

Consider the following (a bit tricky) loop in C++:

```
using namespace std;

list<string> lst;
// Fill the list with some strings or keep it empty depending on something...

auto i = lst.begin(), e = lst.end();
string csv;
if(lst.size())
  do
    csv += *i;
  while(++i != e && (csv += ", ", true));
```

The aim of it is to form the coma-separated string consisting of the initial list members. And it handle right the case of empty list. But I'm in doubt, if the second part of the `while` condition may be optimised out by some (too) smart compiler. Is there any explanations in the standard on the cases like this one?

I understand that this "task" can be fulfilled via different ways, but I'm querying *not* about the CSV-string forming algorithm here.

Thank you.

Comment: `(csv += ", ", true)` has to run every iteration that `++i != e` is not false.  Doing otherwise would change the observable behavior of the code and that is not allowed.

Comment: This is UB if the list is empty, since you're dereferencing `begin()` without checking if it's not the same as `end()` first

Comment: @perivesta, Yes, you are right.

Comment: I'm really struggling to understand why you think this is something that a compiler could optimize out. Perhaps if you explained more of your thinking about that, better answers could be provided (and/or a more suitable duplicate could be found).

Comment: Here is a way you can do this that has completely defined behavior: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/423a1661be110194

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The C++ standard permits optimizations only if they have no observable effects.

In this case the 2nd half of the `while` condition cannot be completely eliminated, because this will have an observable effect. C++ compilers will not remove it.

Comment: To be pedantic, there are rare cases where optimisation is allowed with observable behaviors (NRVO, new expression, floating-point exceptions) see [as-if rule](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/as_if#Notes) for details.

Answer (score 1):

Optimizations are not allowed to change the behavior of your code. So independent of optimizations, your code will always do what you wrote down. That is assuming your code is valid C++ and has no undefined behavior.

Regarding your actual code, I would generally recommend being less clever in order to get easier to understand and maintain code:

```cpp
std::string csv;
bool first = true;
for (std::string entry : lst) {
  if (!first) {
    csv += ", ";
  }
  first = false;
  csv += entry;
}
```

Unlike your code this will also work correctly for empty lists.

Comment: Alternative ways of [idiom-for-iterating-between-each-consecutive-pair-of-elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35372784/idiom-for-iterating-between-each-consecutive-pair-of-elements/35373017#35373017).